# Matching Strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, matching, string-matching

Using Python, how can I check whether 3 consecutive chars within a string (A) are also contained in another string (B)? Is there any built-in function in Python?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
A = FatRadio
B = fradio
```

Assuming that I have defined a threshold of 3, the python script should return true as there are three consecutive characters in B which are also included in A (note that this is the case for 4 and 5 consecutive characters as well).

Comment: Do you mean something like loop over triplet chars from (A) and look for in in (B)?

Comment: If I get it right, yes! So as I wrote bellow, I need python to try all possible combinations (of words of length 3) in its own...

Comment: Also, do you mean three identical chars, or any char triplet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
char_count = 3 # Or whatever you want
if len(A) >= char_count and len(B) >= char_count :
    for i in range(0, len(A) - char_count + 1):
        some_chars = A[i:i+char_count]
        if some_chars in B:
            # Huray!
```

Comment: @user2295350 This solution is broken. Try with `A = "abcdefghijk"` and `B = "zzijk"`. Even though they share a triplet the code doesn't find it.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yeah, I missed that. Fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module:

```
import difflib

def have_common_triplet(a, b):
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    return max(size for _,_,size in matcher.get_matching_blocks()) >= 3
```

Result:

```
>>> have_common_triplet("FatRadio", "fradio")
True
```

Note however that `SequenceMatcher` does much more than finding the first common triplet, hence it could take significant more time than a naive approach.  A simpler solution could be:

```
def have_common_group(a, b, size=3):
     first_indeces = range(len(a) - len(a) % size)
     second_indeces = range(len(b) - len(b) % size)
     seqs = {b[i:i+size] for i in second_indeces}
     return any(a[i:i+size] in seqs for i in first_indeces)
```

Which should perform better, especially when the match is at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any built-in function for this, so I guess the most simple implementation would be something like this:

```
a = 'abcdefgh'
b = 'foofoofooabcfoo'

for i in range(0,len(a)-3):
  if a[i:i+3] in b:
    print 'then true!'
```

Which could be shorten to:

```
search_results = [i for in range(0,len(a)-3) if a[i:i+3] in b]
```